# Solution explorer not updating team projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and have a **Team Project** setup using **Visual Studio Online**.

This is so I can easily stop work from one computer and pick it up on another, seamlessly. It works great, however for some reason I cannot get my solution explorer to display a newly added project, despite the fact I have the latest version of my solution and can see the missing project under the **Source Control Explorer**.

---

### Not showing newest project added to the solution

[image]

### Right clicking on the solution and getting the newest version *should* add the missing project, but doesn't

[image]

### Notice the fact the missing project is showing under the Source Control Explorer

[image]

### And just to confirm, the missing project is actually downloaded

[image]

### Shows up on Visual Studio Online

[image]

## What I've tried:

- Doing a manual get even though I have the latest version

[image]

- Restarting Visual Studio 2015 after doing a get (duh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in which projects show up missing.

This is how I fixed it:

1. Right click on your solution and click "**Add existing project**"

[image]

2. Head to the location where your team project is saved. It's **not** the same as your other projects. Usually is located in `C:\Users\<username>\Source`
3. Navigate to the `.vcxproj` file of the missing solution, and add it.
4. You'll see it appears as if it was always there, however your solution will appear to be "out of date". So right click on your *solution*, and click "**Check in**" then confirm
5. You'll probably notice the message below after you check in your solution. The reason nothing changed is because the missing project was already there just for some reason not displayed by the solution explorer.

   > All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks.  The changes have been undone by the server.